# Is there an alternative for onload on <select>?

Tags: javascript, html, jinja2, selectize.js

I am using jinja templates to compile a form of multiple select blocks based on a template variable dictionary, like this:

```
{% for key, value in some_template_variable_dict.items %}
        <select id="{{ key }}_selector" name="key">
            {% for item in values %}
                <option value="{{ item }}">{{ item }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
{% endfor %}
```

I would like to fire the following wrapper function for selectize on all of the select blocks on loading the document:

```
function selectizeSingleChoice(selector) {
    $('#'+selector).selectize({
        sortField: 'text',
        maxItems: 1,
        create: false,
        highlight: true,
        openOnFocus: true
    });
}
```

The select block does not have an onload event handler, and I cannot put it in a general $(document).ready(); section either, as the exact list of select blocks and their id-s is dependent on user choice. There is also an option that a slightly different version of the selectize wrapper is needed for some of them (e.g. not only one selected option allowed etc), so I cannot fire it on each and every select item either.

A working solution is to insert a script tag inside the for loop, but I dislike it for being messy.

Comment: You could use `document.querySelectorAll('select')` to get a list of all `<select>` elements instead of using 'select by id'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your data is generated dynamically you could mark each select option with a class that specifies it's type like `class="type1"` and `class="type2"` so later you can do separate actions on them from the JS side. Or you could use the [HTML data-*](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) attribute to differentiate them.

Comment: Thanks, this actually works, and looks much better than my solution.